# Display Java Error when Ant Build Fails

Tags: java, ant

I am invoking a Java Class through ant script. Is there any way in which we can display the error message of the Invoked Java class in the Ant Build Fail message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
<target name="test_java">
    <java classname="Test">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${cpath}"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

The `Test` class source code:

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 2;

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(a/0));
}
```

}

The output:

> test_java: 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero 
>     at Test.main(Test.java:7) Java  
>   Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the  task to do this?  If so, you can redirect stderr to a property with the errorproperty attribute, and then include that property in your message in the  task.  You would have to have failonerror="false" and have some other method of detecting the error (a  based on the process status code perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect for the above answers. I think I got a simpler solution. While running the ant script, if we call the command with a -d option in the end, it displays a lot more information alongwith the failure reason for the java class also.

Hence, the command would be :

ant fileName.xml -d

Cheers!